# UIBarButtonItem's action is not called when in a view with a UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a simple UIViewController derived controller which has UITextFields.

Also using IB, I placed a UIToolbar and two UIBarButtonItems. I Ctrl-Drag to add actions to the buttons.

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender { ... }
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender { ... }
```

If I run the code, the actions get called.

**The problem**: I wanted to implement the *tap on background to resignFirstResponder paradigm*, so I added a UITapGestureRecognizer on the root view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    ...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
   }
```

When I have the gesture recognizer, **the actions of the UIBarButtonItems are not called**

How can I have it both ways?

Thanks for any explanations that could help me implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the problem by adding another view and setting the gesture recognizer on that view instead of the root view.

But I still would like to know the explanation to why the gesture recognizer would "eat" the action of the UIBarButtonItem.