# UIBarButtonItem sent action works on iOS 6 but not iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am going to tear my hair out because I cannot think of a logical reason why this occurs on 5 but not 6.  So basically, I have a view presented in modal fashion with a navigation bar and a Cancel button (`UIBarButtonItem` - no custom anything on it, just a standard button) in the navigation bar. When this Cancel button is tapped, I want the modal view to disappear. This works just fine in iOS 6. But for iOS 5 it refuses to work for 2 out of 3 places I have it in my code. What's odd to me is that it works on one but not the other two.

Using storyboards, I right click the button, click on "selector" under Sent Actions, and drag over to the appropriate `IBAction` method in my view controller's .h file. The link is successfully confirmed with the little blinking animation in Xcode. When I run the app on iOS 6 (simulator or device doesn't matter), the method is successfully executed upon button tap and my modal view dismissed. However, on iOS 5, the method is never even called (I set breakpoints inside the method to see if they would be hit). I've even tried switching the argument in my `IBAction` method from `id` to `UIBarButtonItem *`. No cigar, though.

I've also tried programmatically (in `viewDidLoad`) setting the cancel button's action to a selector. I've even set the target to the VC. No cigar again.  Here is a screenshots of my current setup:

[image: Please note the IBAction methods]

Please note the `IBAction` methods.

Is there some magical clause in the documentation that I missed? Something awfully special I need to do in order to get it to work in iOS 5? It sure seems like a bug to me, but I'm still fairly new to this stuff so what do I know.

I am using Xcode 4.5.2 and storyboards, and targeting iOS 5 and iOS 6 for the release.

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: A few things:  1) We need to see some code; 2) A picture of your outlet in the XIB 3) Have you tried removing the app from both simulators and running a clean build?

Comment: I will add a screenshot. I have removed and replaced app and still same issue. Cleaned, analyzed, re-built project too.

Comment: Hi Stephan !
Any luck solving the problem ?
My hair also in danger because of exactlly the same problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a separate `UIView` that resides under my textfields and button and below the navigation bar/title. I added the tap gesture to that programmatically, and that seems to recognize both my tap and the cancel button's action. I still would like to know why the tap gesture swallows up the `UIBarButtonItem`'s action if the gesture is on the root view. [This question helped me figure this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253099/uibarbuttonitems-action-is-not-called-when-in-a-view-with-a-uigesturerecognizer). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be problem of using **GestureRecognizer** please comment that code and try it...

Comment: Ohhh my, that seems to have worked. I wonder why the gesture recognizer messes it up. What of my cancel button, though? I don't believe I can easily add a gesture recognizer to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can ***exclude view/control from gesture recognizer*** using following delegate method.

`// UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    // exclude your view from gesture recognizer
    if(yourView == touch.view)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    // 
    return YES;
}
```